# How can I move videos from Google Drive to Apple Photos on iPad?

Tags: ipad, photos, google-apps

My uncle has a lot of videos in Google Drive on his iPad. In Google Drive i can’t find a way to export/save to Photos. I can only move to another Google drive but not onto the native Photos app. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

From [this Google article:](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423534?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en)

> Open the Google Drive app.
>
> Next to the file you want to download, tap More.
>
> Tap Send a copy.
>
> Depending on your file, tap Save image or Save video.

If you want to save multiple at once you will need to move the files to Google Photos and have them in a folder.

Then:

> On your iPhone or iPad, open the Google Drive app.
>
> Tap Menu and then Settings.
>
> Under Google Photos, turn on Auto Add. At the top, tap Back.
>
> Find and open the Google Photos folder.
>
> Select the folder you want to download.
>
> Tap More and then  Select All and then Download.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I can “each” video individually but there are hundreds. When I ‘Select All’ there is a Google style arrow button at the top right which seems to be restricted to the Googleverse. Selecting multiple videos disables the little ... ellipsis button.

Comment: @NicCottrell Edited post

Comment: Awesome! I’ll give it a try!

Comment: Seems like the service changed June 2018 and now I have to do some settings from the Google Photos app instead